# find creation date of folders in a directory

Tags: date, directory, find

I am trying to use the below to output a the `date` a folder was created in a specific directory.  The command does create an `out` file, but it is empty.  Also if there are two folders created on the same date, how can they be distinguished?  Thank you :).

**directory**

```
123
456
456
789
```

**code**

```
find /home/cmccabe/nfs/exportedReports/directory -iname "*.c" > /home/cmccabe/nfs/exportedReports/directory/out
```

**desired output**

```
123 8-13-2016
456 8-17-2016_1
456 8-17-2016_2
789 8-25-2016
```

Comment: All that would do is print the names of the files that have a `.c` extension. If the output is empty, it means that there are no such files (or perhaps that you can't see them). Where is the code to output the dates? Incidentally, many, probably most, Unix file systems don't record creation times.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get any useful answers unless you update your question with more information. Do the folder names reflect the dates they were created? Are you relying on the names being accurate? If so, that information definitely needs to be in the question. BTW, `YYYY-MM-DD` is a better date format; it's the standard (ISO 8601), it's unambiguous (`8-9-2016` could be either Aug 9 or Sep 8), and it sorts correctly.)